# interaction of footage in 3D scene

Tags: compositing-nodes, tracking

Any Ideas on how to make Gloss and Transmission interact with the footage ?
I tried modeling those items on the footage but the camera wasn't matched perfectly.
So any chance on doing the trick on Comp ?

[image: Fotage]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use the built-in uploader when adding images. See: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Comment: my apologies , i was having issues on adding more pictures earlier didnt realized i need to add in on next line.

Comment: Don't get it. What's your question? How to get the sphere and the cube look "right"?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i just need to add as material the Original Footage on a plane and cover the Camera's Field of View .

[image: Just need to set the Unwrap to Project from view on Camera mode]

[image]

[image]